# WebMvcTest and entitMangerFactory missing reference

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot 3

I try to do a test from the controller

```
userManager.findByUa
```

call a repository

Test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class)
public class UserConnectionControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserManager userManager;

    @Test
    public void retrieveUserConnection() throws Exception{

        UserConnection mockUserConnection = new UserConnection(158791, "Paul Smith", "1123977", "01");

mockUserConnection.setDisabled(false);

        String expected = """
        {
            "userId": 158791,
                "name": "Paul Smith",
                "userAccess": "1123977",
                "userType": "01",
                "disabled": false
        }
        """;

        Mockito.when(userManager.findByUa(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockUserConnection);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                "/users/1123977").accept(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();


        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, result.getResponse()
                .getContentAsString(), false);

    }

}
```

When i run this test, i get this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting
> constructor argument

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = { "com.acme.extranet", "com.acme.common" }
)
@EntityScan("com.acme.common")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.common")
public class ExtranetApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExtranetApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My entity and repository and in the common package who is a jar library use in the Extranet application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that your context and test strategy, so it is not an accurate hint.
I think there are two options.

#### 1. Without @MockBean

If you just want to use UserManager as test double, just make mock object by Mockito's static method.
Remove dependencies of JPA for test.

```java
package action.in.blog;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class)
public class TempTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private UserManager userManager;

    @Test
    void test() {
        userManager = Mockito.mock(UserManager.class);
        when(userManager.findAll()).thenReturn(
                List.of(new User(111))
        );


        List<User> result = userManager.findAll();


        assertThat(mockMvc != null, equalTo(true));
        assertThat(result.get(0).getId(), equalTo(111L));
    }
}
```

#### 2. Using @SpringBooTest

@WebMvcTest annotation provide minimal context for MVC test.
So that cannot use JPA functionalities.
And You need to append two annotations.

- @AutoConfigureMockMvc for MockMvc injection.
- @Transational for rollback transaction after test.

```java
package action.in.blog;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
public class TempSecondTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserManager userManager;

    @Test
    void test() {
        when(userManager.findAll()).thenReturn(
                List.of(new User(111))
        );


        List<User> result = userManager.findAll();


        assertThat(mockMvc != null, equalTo(true));
        assertThat(result.get(0).getId(), equalTo(111L));
    }
}
```